# How can I dynamically populate a UITableView control?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Using `UITableView`, I can display a list of items using an array in `rootViewTabel`, how can I display another list in the `nextView` of the table?

My first view displays a list of months from jan - dec.

On selecting  a particular month I want to display the list of festivals for that month in the same table.

What code should I include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the app launches use your root view controller to display the list of months. When the user taps on a particular cell, push another view controller which will in turn display the list of festivals for the selected month.

Following this way would be very easy to learn and implement.

Here are a few links that will help you learn and implement it easily.

- [Easy custom UITableView drawing](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)
- [iPhone Programming Tutorial – Populating UITableView With An NSArray](http://icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/)

So go ahead and code...